# Self-contained JNLP launcher + data file

Tags: java, swing, jnlp

I've got a JNLP editor application that saves data to data files. I'd like to allow users to send self-container viewer applications+data in a single file.

Ideally, this self-contained file would be a double-clickable .jar file containing the data file and anything needed to bootstrap the JNLP application.  Do you have a recommendation for how to get a .jar file to launch a JNLP and tell it the app open a specific file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that just occurred to me is to have the .jar file write some Preference value for which file to open, then just open the JNLP URL without any arguments. When the JNLP launches, it can check for the Preference value and load the appropriate file.  This seems nicer than trying to hack a dynamic JNLP definition file on the server.